# How to change value inside of a list through user input with specific format?

Tags: python

This is my current Python code:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import os
from PIL import Image
import os


#Window




# SQL
try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='signoff',
                                         user='root',
                                         password='test')
    sql_select_Query = "select url from img where id =%s"
    idList = [1,]
    id = idList
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql_select_Query, id)
    records = cursor.fetchone()
    print()
    for row in records:
        print(row)


except Error as e:
    print("Error reading data from MySQL table", e)

finally:
    if (connection.is_connected()):
        connection.close()
        cursor.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")

#Open image
img = row
os.startfile(img)
```

I am going to add this in:

```
change = input()
```

How can I replace the number inside the current list for `idList = [1,]`

As an example, if I type 2 in the prompted input, then idList changes to the following: `idList = [2,]`

how can I achieve this?

Comment: You could easily have the value within `idList` be a variable, e.g. `idList = [int(change),]`, being sure to convert the string input to an integer, of course

Comment: That's perfect @natn2323 learned something new! :D

Comment: No problem, @98Ed. I moved my comment to the answer section. Feel free to mark is as the selected answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comment, you can easily have the value within `idList` be a variable, e.g. `idList = [int(change),]`, being sure to convert the string input to an integer, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have one number inside the list you could achieve it with:

```
idList = [int(input())]
```

If you want to replace the first number of your list:

```
idList = [int(input())] + idList[1:]
```

Edit:

If you are going to save the input() in "change"

```
idList = [int(change)]
```

or:

```
idList = [int(change)] + idList[1:]
```